# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value inside an entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I want an UICollectionViewCell to be deleted when the delete button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonClicked() {

    error here:    delegate?.deleteTrigger(clothes!)

}
```

clothes:

```
var clothes: Clothes? {
        didSet {

            updateUI()
        }
    }

func deleteTrigger:

 func deleteTrigger(clothes: Clothes){

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context)


        if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context) {



        let indexPath = NSIndexPath()

        //var cat : Category = clothing as! Category
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Clothes")

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", self.selectedCategory!)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        var error: NSError? = nil
        var clothesArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)!
        managedContext.deleteObject(clothesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
        clothesArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])

        if (!managedContext.save(&error)) {
            abort()


        }

        }
```

Clothes is an entity in Core Data.  Does anyone know why I am getting this error?  I am trying to delete a collectionViewCell from core data with in a one-to-many relationship.  Category is the parent entity and Clothes is the entity within the Category.

Comment: You are saying `delegate?.deleteTrigger(clothes!)` - any time you use an exclamation mark, you are begging to crash. That is what the exclamation mark _means_ in Swift. You did crash. No big surprise. If you don't want to, don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, your value is nil. You need to unwrap the variable before you can do anything with it. Try this:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonClicked() 
{
  if var clothes = clothes
  {
    delegate?.deleteTrigger(clothes)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a property `clothes`:

```
var clothes: Clothes?
```

You never gave it any *value*, so it is `nil`. Thus when you force-unwrap it by saying `clothes!`, you crash.

Comment: I still get the same error when I change var clothes: Clothes? to var clothes: Clothes! and when I change delegate?.deleteTrigger(clothes!) to delegate?.deleteTrigger(clothes) @matt

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. You are _still_ not giving this variable any value. All you did was move the exclamation mark around.